# the meaning of save on more good times

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

> **save on** more good times

It's from an ad.

Why did we use **save on** rather than **save at**, as I usually collocate at with time.

Does it mean I can get savings at the next times?

Comment: I would use "save for more good times", but being a slogan could be written with words or context left out, same as you often see in news headlines. Since you have the ad, can you add what you think they meant, even if written incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are promised to save is *money*, not time.

**Save** *when spending money* **on more good times**.

"Good times" is what you are buying, meaning "fun" or "recreation activities". They are offering a discount if you buy more (quantity) of whatever they are offering.